# WPF - Grouping collection by type and templating by type

Tags: c#, wpf

Using these classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : Person
{
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
}
```

And this ViewModel class:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

How can I design my view so that I can group the elements of `MainViewModel.Persons` by their derived class `Type` and show a `<ContentControl>` for each grouping AND the `<ContentControl>` should use a different `DataTemplate` depending on what `Type` belong to the particular group?

Assume that I have a large amount of classes that derive from `Person` and my `MainViewModel.Persons` collection  could contain any of these derived classes all at once.

I would also like to be able to declare my various `DataTemplate` in XAML if possible.

Comment: GetType() returns the most derived type, so `foreach (var person in persons){Console.WriteLine(GetType().Name);}` will print, "Customer, Employee" etc.. which should be a good starting point.

Comment: @Quantic How can this help me though?

Comment: I think you need an Observable collection of observable collections combined with  a template selector on the parent. That collection could be maintained by listening to the CollectionChanged event of the original Persons observable collection.

Comment: Is there any chance that your Person could be an Employee and a Customer simultaneously? Doesn't have to be those specifically. If you're going to allow for a "large amount of classes that drive from Person" and there's any chance of a person filling multiple roles, you'll regret this. Furthermore, I think this sort of inheritance doesn't play nice with things like CSLA or Entity Framework.

Comment: @Guttsy No, There is no chance of this happening in this application.

Comment: @KyleV. Hm, via reflection you could figure out the amount of different types, create that number of content controls, assign the master collection to each one of them and in the template have something that would collapse all instances that are not of a specific type. That, however, seems to me as a bad hack and is not really maintainable. Plus you have to process all data as many times as you have different types in the collection.

Comment: @FrankJ I think this might be the solution I need. Could you give me an example of how this would work? EDIT: Referring to your first proposed solution of a ObservableCollection of ObserveableCollections.

Comment: I can point you into the direction of maintaining the collections but I have done very little with template selectors. Plus I don't think this is going to be a small code base, but a whole project. Hence just the comment to guide you into the right direction and not an answer...

Answer (score 2):

You can build out three different DataTemplates using DataType. It will automatically pick the template for the most-derived type. The one downside is that your templates are going to be a bit repetitive since each template gets to redefine the basic information provided by Person's template.

To group the data, you have two approaches:

1. ObservableCollection of ObservableCollections
2. CollectionViewSource

If you wanted to use option 1, you could use LINQ's GroupBy method, e.g.

```
Persons.GroupBy(_ => _.GetType())
```

and then massage it into an ObservableCollection. However, if your collection of people changes after the screen is loaded, you have to either rebuild the whole collection or subscribe to the CollectionChanged event and sync the changes yourself.

I'm going to suggest option 2 because it's magical and awesome. With the IsLiveGroupingRequested set to true on the CollectionViewSource, WPF should automatically handle the grouping for you. To accommodate this, however, I added a new property to your Person object: PersonType. (This would work out better than using the type name if you ended up localizing your application though!)

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="viewSource" Source="{Binding Path=Persons}" IsLiveGroupingRequested="True">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="PersonType" />
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myNamespace:Person}"> ... </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myNamespace:Employee}"> ... </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myNamespace:Customer}"> ... </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource viewSource}" />
    </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

Note the extra namespace:

```
xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I wanted but it's just missing one thing: I wanted my `DataTemplate` to be applied at the group level. For example: If I wanted to show a `DataGrid` control for each group with its `ItemSource` set to the members of the group, and have the column headers be different depending on the `Type` contained in the group. So in this case `Employees` would be in one grid with certain headers and `Customers` in a different grid with different headers.